# Renting a car in San Diego and driving it down the Baja Penninsula Mexico

Tags: car-rentals, mexico

I've heard conflicting reports on whether you can rent a car in the US and drive it into Mexico.  We are going on a 2 week trip to the Baja Peninsula and want to fly into San Diego and rent a car to drive down.

Is it possible? If so what things should I be careful/worried about? Will the rental agency set me up with everything I need to legally drive in Mexico?

With that said, any danger or concerns or tips for driving the most direct route from San Diego, through Tijuana, and half way down the Peninsula?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to rent a car in Tijuana? Also likely significantly cheaper.

Comment: @GregHewgill, I would do that but what would be the best way to get from the San Diego airport to the rental car station across the border?

Comment: @jfeust a taxi is about $50, apparently.  It costs me more than that to get from JFK to my home in Brooklyn.  For more information, and for other options including public transit, see http://www.sandiegotraveltips.com/public/Transportation_from_San_Diego_Airport_to_Mexico.cfm.  Also, Google maps will give you transit directions; it takes about an hour.

Comment: @jfeust, I did this a while back.  I expect you're headed to the national park south of Ensenada.  The big issue is being sure to use high quality petrol IMHO